# Calculate MLEs numerically

Tags: probability

I have a random variable $r$, which is define as $r=f(C,\beta, U)$, $C$ and $\beta$ are both parameters and U is distributed as uniform[0,1]. I want to get MLEs of C and $\beta$. My $f()$ is quite complicated thus I am not able to deduce a closed form of the density of $r$, so I am thinking about doing that numerically.

I do have a set of data, which is true $r$. Obviously, I want to select C and $\beta$ to make the density be the closest to the trun data.

Can anyone provide some examples?

Comment: I'm not so sure that the MLE is the right way to go when you can't evaluate the density. You have a discrete distribution of "true data", and using your f as a black box, you have a way to generate discrete distributions with particular values of the parameters. You could choose a metric between distributions (for example, $\| F - G \|_{\infty}$, where $F,G$ are CDFs) and aim to minimize the distance between your generated distribution and the given data.

Comment: The only alternative that I can see would be to come up with some recipe for converting discrete distributions into "interpolating densities", where you are essentially performing an interpolation procedure where in between each cell you should have a nonnegative function with a prespecified integral, and the overall density should be continuously differentiable.

Comment: I think this can be done: you have n grid points, n-1 cells, n-2 interfaces, and 2 boundary conditions. Each cell has an integral equation, each interface has two regularity equations, and you have the two boundary conditions, for a total of 3n-3 equations. So that should be doable using piecewise quadratic functions. It is still not so clear where the endpoints should be, though; they shouldn't be the smallest and largest observed values, because those values were *observed* so they should have positive density.